# Tilde character in password interferes with SSH login

Tags: password, ssh, authentication

From my Mac I sometimes access remote machines with `ssh` providing a username and password.

The password is generated and sometimes contains a `~`. As soon as I hit the `~` in the password, I get some kind of subshell(?):

```
user's Password:
ssh>
```

Is there a way to escape or escape or circumvent this?

I'm on macOS Montery (12.6).

Comment: remove the tilde form the acceptable character list used for password generation.

Comment: Have you considered public key authentication? https://web.archive.org/web/20220925150358/https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From `man ssh`

```
-e escape_char
  Sets the escape character for sessions with a pty (default: `~' ) . 
  The escape character is only recognized at the beginning of a line.
  The escape character followed by a dot (`.' ) closes the connection;
  followed by control-Z suspends the connection; and followed by
  itself sends the escape character once. Setting the character to ``none''
  disables any escapes and makes the session fully transparent
```

So running `ssh -e none user@host` should avoid the problem.

Comment: Later in the man page, there's  also a list of all the escapes. `~C` is the one that starts a shell (so I guess we know the first two characters of their password).

Answer (score 9):

When asked for the password, enter one arbitrary character like `x` and immediately backspace it, then put in your password. This approach works at any level of nesting, and it will let you keep escapes enabled, so that you can still use them later in the session if you want to.

Answer (score 9):

From my local testing, This should only be happening if the tilde is the first character after you hit enter. You can enter a literal tilde by just hitting it twice. The first will be captured by ssh and the second will go through.

You can see this yourself by doing:

```
$ read answer
~~this is a string~~
$ echo $answer
~this is a string~~
```

It becomes trickier if your ssh sessions are even more deeply nested. For those, you’d need one more tilde for each nested level.